# Close simple jQuery popup on body click

Tags: jquery, html, geolocation

I have a simple jQuery popup that is taking your ip, and then displaying certain information based off of your location. Geolocation. I am trying to make it, so when you click anywhere on the body it will then close the popup. For some reason this is not working.

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="message" style="padding:30px;">
    <h1>Hola!</h1>
    <p>You are in US</p>
  </div>  
</div>



jQuery.ajax( { 
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {
    jQuery('#city').html(location.city);
    jQuery('#region-code').html(location.region_code);
    jQuery('#region-name').html(location.region_name);
    jQuery('#areacode').html(location.areacode);
    jQuery('#ip').html(location.ip);
    jQuery('#zipcode').html(location.zipcode);
    jQuery('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
    jQuery('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
    jQuery('#country-name').html(location.country_name);
    jQuery('#country-code').html(location.country_code);
  }
} );

jQuery.ajax( { 
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {

    if (location.country_code === 'US') {

      $('#message').parent().show();
    }
  }
} );

jQuery('html') //set for html for jsfiddle, but should be 'body'
              .bind(
               'click',
               function(e){
            if(
             jQuery('#message').dialog('isOpen')
             && !jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog, a')
             && !jQuery(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog').length
            ){
             jQuery('#message').dialog('close');
            }
               }
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the jquery UI dialog you need to bind the close method to the node you'd like to trigger closing the dialog.

```js
  // instantiate the dialog
  $(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      open: function() {

        // if condition is met then bind click to the body and close the dialog  

            jQuery('body').bind('click', function() {
              jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })

       // end if

      }
    });
  });

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(location) {
      jQuery('#city').html(location.city);
      jQuery('#region-code').html(location.region_code);
      jQuery('#region-name').html(location.region_name);
      jQuery('#areacode').html(location.areacode);
      jQuery('#ip').html(location.ip);
      jQuery('#zipcode').html(location.zipcode);
      jQuery('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
      jQuery('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
      jQuery('#country-name').html(location.country_name);
      jQuery('#country-code').html(location.country_code);
    }
  });

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(location) {

      if (location.country_code === 'US') {

        $('#message').parent().show();
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<div id="dialog">
  <div id="message" style="padding:30px;">
    <h1>Hola!</h1>
    <p>You are in US</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @JeffRodger It worked in codepen when I wrote the code for you.  Do you have anything else to go on other than it's not working?  What's your console say?

Comment: Here is the attached codepen, with your code exactly: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxgOEW click outside the text and nothing disappears.

Comment: @JeffRodger Your code pen did not add jquery and jquery UI, how would you expect it to work?  I've since updated this for you, please see the working code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQNoga try clicking anywhere in the blue area.